# Android Map of own application not shown

Tags: android, android-mapview, api-key

I have a strange problem with my android application. I implemented maps, i got the api-key as it should be done, inserted it in my app....when i launch the app on my phone directly through Eclipse, it works. When i export the app into an apk and pass it to friends in order to test it on other phones, tha map is never shown and the app crashes, because the mapController in null:

```
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.google.android.maps.MapController.animateTo(MapController.java:232)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.google.android.maps.MapController.animateTo(MapController.java:203)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.emaborsa.cablePark.activities.MainActivity$5.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:492)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.emaborsa.cablePark.popUpMenu.MapPopupMenu$1.onClick(MapPopupMenu.java:163)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-24 14:52:07.425: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("Log", "onCreate()");

    this.application = (CableParkApplication) getApplication();
    database = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == VERTICAL) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_v);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_h);
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        this.currentView = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_VIEW);
        this.mapType = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(MAP_TYPE);
        this.country = savedInstanceState.getString(COUNTRY);
        showMapMenu((LinearLayout) ((ImageView) mapViewContainer.findViewById(R.id.map_menu_open)).getParent());
    }

    initViews();

    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(getApplicationContext(), mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    mapHandler = new MapHandler(this, mapView);
    mapHandler.initMap(mapType);
    addListeners();

    showActualFrame();

}

protected void initViews() {
    // initializes main view
    mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    LinearLayout main_view_vertical = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mainview_v, null);
    mainView.addView(main_view_vertical);

    // initializes search view
    searchMainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    LinearLayout search_view_vertical = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.searchview_v, null);
    searchMainView.addView(search_view_vertical);
    searchTextCountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectCountry);
    selectCountryFlag = (ImageView) searchMainView.findViewById(R.id.selectCountryFlag);
    searchEditTextKey = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEditTextKey);
    searchTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchTextView);
    searchButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);

    if (country != null && !country.equals("")) {
        searchTextCountry.setText(country);
        String flag = country.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(flag, "drawable", CableParkApplication.PACKAGE);
        selectCountryFlag.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    // initializes diary view
    diaryMainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.diaryView);
    LinearLayout diary_view_vertical = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.diaryview_v, null);
    diaryMainView.addView(diary_view_vertical);

    // initializes map(container) view
    mapViewContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapViewContainer);
    LinearLayout map_view_container_vertical = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mapviewcontainer_v, null);
    mapViewContainer.addView(map_view_container_vertical);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    if (!application.isLoaded()) {
        application.setLoaded(true);
        Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
        myFadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new SplashAnimation(MainActivity.this, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getRotation()));
        mainView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.buttonsLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.id).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    // initializes bottom buttons
    searchImageLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchImageLayout);
    mapImageLayout = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapImageLayout));
    diaryImageLayout = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.diaryImageLayout));

}

private void addListeners() {

    searchButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                searchButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.singlebuttondown);
                searchTextView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                searchButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.singlebutton);
                searchTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
                if (doSearch()) {
                    showSearchResult();
                    hideSoftPad();
                    showMap(null);
                } else {
                    showNoResultDialog();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    searchEditTextKey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (searchEditTextKey.getText().toString().equals("....?")) {
                searchEditTextKey.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    searchEditTextKey.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                if (doSearch()) {
                    showSearchResult();
                    hideSoftPad();
                    showMap(null);
                } else {
                    showNoResultDialog();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

protected void showActualFrame() {

    switch (currentView) {
    case SEARCH:
        showSearch(searchMainView);
        break;
    case MAP:
        showMap(mapView);
        break;
    case DIARY:
        showDiary(diaryMainView);
        break;
    default:
        showFrame(mainView);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.e("Log", "onResume()");
    broadcastReceiver = new MessageReceiver();
    IntentFilter inFilter = new IntentFilter();
    inFilter.addAction(CableParkApplication.CANCEL);
    inFilter.addAction(CableParkApplication.COUNTRY);
    inFilter.addAction(CableParkApplication.SINGLE_PARK);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, inFilter);
    super.onResume();
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    this.zoomLevel = mapView.getZoomLevel();
    this.mapCenter = mapView.getMapCenter();
    super.onPause();
    myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.disableCompass();
    Log.e("Log", "onPause()");
}

// customized the onBackButton
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Leave?").setCancelable(false).setMessage("Close the application?").setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public void showSearch(View v) {
    mapView.removeAllViews();
    currentView = SEARCH;
    searchEditTextKey.setText("");
    setBackground(searchImageLayout);
    showFrame(searchMainView);
}

public void showMap(View v) {
    currentView = MAP;
    setBackground(mapImageLayout);
    showFrame(mapViewContainer);
    mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void showDiary(View v) {
    mapView.removeAllViews();
    currentView = DIARY;
    setBackground(diaryImageLayout);
    showFrame(diaryMainView);
}

protected void showFrame(View view) {
    mainView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mapView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mapViewContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    diaryMainView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    searchMainView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

protected void setBackground(LinearLayout layout) {
    searchImageLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttons);
    mapImageLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttons);
    diaryImageLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttons);
    layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonsdown);
}


private boolean doSearch() {
    String key = searchEditTextKey.getText().toString();
    String country = (String) searchTextCountry.getText();
    database.connectForReading();
    Vector<Park> parks = database.getParks(country, key);
    database.disconnect();
    application.setParkSearch(parks);
    return parks.size() > 0;
}

private void showSearchResult() {
    Vector<Park> parks = application.getParkSearch();
    mapHandler.drawGeopoints(parks);
    CenterGeoPointCalculator cgpc = new CenterGeoPointCalculator(parks);
    cgpc.calc();
    mapHandler.centerMap(cgpc, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation());
    mapView.getController().animateTo(cgpc.getCenterPoint());

}

public void showCountriesDialog(View v) {
    searchTextCountry.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    CountriesAdapter adapter = new CountriesAdapter(MainActivity.this, application.getCountries());
    dialog = new CountriesDialog(MainActivity.this, adapter);
    dialog.show();

}

public void showNoResultDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("No parks found.\nTry another country or another search key.").setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("OK", null);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(CableParkApplication.COUNTRY)) {
            country = intent.getStringExtra("country");
            searchTextCountry.setText(country);
            String flag = country.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
            int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(flag, "drawable", CableParkApplication.PACKAGE);
            selectCountryFlag.setImageResource(resId);
            searchTextCountry.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dialog.dismiss();

        } else if (action.equals(CableParkApplication.COUNTRY)) {
            searchTextCountry.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dialog.dismiss();

        } else if (action.equals(CableParkApplication.SINGLE_PARK)) {
            int parkId = intent.getIntExtra("park", -1);
            if (parkId > 0) {
                mapView.removeAllViews();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, SinglePark.class);
                i.putExtra("park", parkId);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.e("Log", "onSaveInstanceState()");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (popupMenu != null) {
        popupMenu.dismiss();
    }
    outState.putInt(CURRENT_VIEW, currentView);
    outState.putBoolean(MAP_TYPE, mapType);
    outState.putString(COUNTRY, (String) searchTextCountry.getText());
}

public void showMapMenu(View v) {
    mapView.removeAllViews();
    popupMenu = new MapPopupMenu(this);

    final ImageView mapMenuOpen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_menu_open);
    mapMenuOpen.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_close);

    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location);
    if (mapView.getZoomLevel() < 5
            || (myLocationOverlay.isMyLocationEnabled() && !mapHandler.isMyLocationVisible(application.getCurrentLocation()))) {
        MenuEntry myLocation = new MenuEntry(ID_MOVE_TO_ME, "Show", image);
        popupMenu.addActionItem(myLocation);

    } else if (myLocationOverlay.isMyLocationEnabled()) {
        MenuEntry hideLocation = new MenuEntry(ID_DISABLE_LOC, "Hide", image);
        popupMenu.addActionItem(hideLocation);

    } else {
        MenuEntry showLocation = new MenuEntry(ID_ENABLE_LOC, "Show", image);
        popupMenu.addActionItem(showLocation);
    }

    image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.compass);
    if (myLocationOverlay.isCompassEnabled()) {
        MenuEntry hideCompass = new MenuEntry(ID_DISABLE_COMP, "Hide", image);
        popupMenu.addActionItem(hideCompass);

    } else {
        MenuEntry showCompass = new MenuEntry(ID_ENABLE_COMP, "Show", image);
        popupMenu.addActionItem(showCompass);

    }

    image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_menu);
    if (mapHandler.getShownMap() == MapHandler.SATELLITE) {
        MenuEntry showMap = new MenuEntry(ID_SHOW_MAP, "Map", image);
        popupMenu.addActionItem(showMap);

    } else {
        MenuEntry showTraffic = new MenuEntry(ID_SHOW_TRAFFIC, "Hybrid", image);
        popupMenu.addActionItem(showTraffic);

    }

    popupMenu.setAnimStyle(MapPopupMenu.ANIM_GROW_FROM_RIGHT);

    // Set listener for action item clicked
    popupMenu.setOnActionItemClickListener(new MapPopupMenu.OnActionItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(MapPopupMenu source, int pos, int actionId) {
            switch (actionId) {
            case ID_DISABLE_COMP:
                myLocationOverlay.disableCompass();
                break;

            case ID_ENABLE_COMP:
                myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
                break;

            case ID_DISABLE_LOC:
                myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
                break;

            case ID_ENABLE_LOC:
                myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
                mapView.getController().animateTo(application.getCurrentLocation());//line 492 controller seems to be null...
                break;

            case ID_SHOW_MAP:
                mapType = mapHandler.showMap(MapHandler.MAP);
                break;

            case ID_SHOW_TRAFFIC:
                mapType = mapHandler.showMap(MapHandler.SATELLITE);
                break;

            case ID_MOVE_TO_ME:
                myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
                mapView.getController().animateTo(application.getCurrentLocation());
                mapView.getController().setZoom(MapHandler.MYLOCATION_ZOOM);
                break;
            }
            mapMenuOpen.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_open);

        }
    });

    popupMenu.setOnDismissListener(new MapPopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {

        public void onDismiss() {
            mapMenuOpen.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_open);
        }
    });

    popupMenu.show(v, mapMenuOpen);
}

private void hideSoftPad() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchEditTextKey.getWindowToken(), 0);
}


@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    mapView.getController().setZoom(zoomLevel);
    mapView.getController().setCenter(mapCenter);
    Log.e("Log", "onRestart()");
    super.onRestart();
}
```

}

my getCurrentLocation() method:

```
public GeoPoint getCurrentLocation() {

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        return new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

...if the method returns null, i understand the Exception. But how could it return something on my  phone, and null on all other phones?

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: which code should i post? I repeat: on my Galaxy S2 it works. If i EXPORT the apk on another phone, it crashes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"because the mapController in null" -- no, it is not. You can tell this by reading the stack trace. If your `MapController` were `null`, you could not possibly be executing the `animateTo()` method in `MapController`. `animateTo()` is *referring* to something that is `null`.

The most likely thing to be `null` that `animateTo()` would complain about would be the passed-in parameter value, `application.getCurrentLocation()`.

Comment: OK, now i've understood (i hope so). I'm using Context.LOCATION_SERVICE which refers on GPS. If a phone never used GPS the last known location is null. I should try so combine things with NETWORK_PROVIDER.
Am i right?

Comment: @Emaborsa: That might help, but `getLastKnownLocation()` is perfectly capable of returning `null` at any point. You need to be able to handle that scenario without crashing.

Comment: I re-wrote the code, i added the LocationListener in order to listen NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER...and defined onLocationChanged(Location location). In this way i should have always the last location....am i right? Forthermore i changed the rest of the code, i check if the returned value == null and operate accordingly.
Something else?

Comment: @Emaborsa: "In this way i should have always the last location....am i right?" -- I cannot answer that. "Something else?" -- I cannot answer that, either.

Comment: TEsts done: The app doesn't give nullpointerexception anymore....but the map doesn't show up. On my phone it shows up, but not at others.

Comment: ...now i've got it. I didn't know that there are two keys needed. One for the debug and one for the final signed application.

Answer (score 0):

To show map on device you are exporting **Signed APK** then you need to generate **MAP API** key using **release key**.

read [this](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-map-api-key.html) tutorial carefully

Comment: As i have already written, on my phone IT WORKS.... actually i already have MY Api-Key.

Answer (score 0):

**[1]** First of all, **Declare your application as Global** in MainActivity as

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    public Application application;  // <---------- DECLARE IT HERE

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

**[2]** Then declare all other needed object as Global

**[3]** Then put check condition on Line No 492 for which object it gives NullPointerException as

```
If(null == mapView)
    System.out.println("mapView NULL");
If(null == application)
    System.out.println("application NULL");
```

**[4]** Make needed changes of Null Found Object.

Comment: Neither `mapView` nor `application` are `null`, as you can tell by reading the stack trace.

Comment: guys...i repeat:on my phone it works.... i don't understand why it doesn't on others.
I think there is a problem with the map, since the error appears by calling the MapController from the mapView.